# PhantomJS Working on Server but Not XAMPP

Tags: php, phantomjs

I have problem with phantomJS at XAMPP(Installed) MAC. Last time, I am using XAMPP-VM (for Mac) but since update to Monterey. It does not work. I have problem with a new environment here. When trying to run PhantomJS from PHP. It shows

> Fatal error: Uncaught JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\NotWritableException:
> File could not be written to system as target is not writable:
> /var/folders/gd/6f7z77vj3ps0lvnyj88pxg_40000gn/T/b17136c6c91e8bb1fc7b
> in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Cache/FileCache.php:65
> Stack trace: #0
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php(188):
> JonnyW\PhantomJs\Cache\FileCache->save('b17136c6c91e8bb...',
> '\n(function(W,K)...') #1
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php(98):
> JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Procedure->write('\n(function(W,K)...') #2
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/ProcedureValidator.php(84):
> JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Procedure->run(Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Input),
> Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Output)) #3
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-pha in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Cache/FileCache.php
> on line 65

Here is the code

```
$client = Client::getInstance();

$client->getEngine()->setPath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/bin/phantomjs');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--cookies-file=' . $cookies);
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($url, 'GET');
$request->addSetting('userAgent', $userAgent);
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
```

Things I have done.

1. Changing permission to 777 (for bin & the files inside it) (For Test Purpose)
2. Installing phantomJS on my Mac

Comment: _"Changing permission to 777 (for bin & the files inside it)"_ - sounds to me like the path it is actually complaining about, was `/var/folders/gd/6f7z77vj3ps0lvnyj88pxg_40000gn/T/b17136c6c91e8bb1fc7b`?

Comment: Regarding the error "File could not be written to system as target is not writable". Last time, it was 775 in bin folder. I have no idea, So then I tried to set into 777. However, it still does not work. Any idea regarding this matter?

Comment: I was trying to ask you whether you tried to set it for the _correct_ folder(s) to begin with ...

Comment: I have set the correct folder. I think its bug from PhantomJS itself. It is actually working on the server but not localhost

Comment: (Need to make sure we are talking about the same thing here.) You said you set 777 _"for bin & the files inside it"_. The path the error message is talking about, `/var/folders/gd/6f7z77vj3ps0lvnyj88pxg_40000gn/T/b17136c6c91e8bb1fc7b`, is not "in `bin`" ... so did you set permissions explicitly for the path the error message mentioned, yes or no?

Comment: I have tried to go to /var in XAMPP folder set into 775 and create directory "folders" with the same permission. However, it still does not work

Comment: It is working, I put sys_temp_dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/" in php.ini. The main problem is the xampp is trying to access the /var in mac folder, it has no access even permission is set to 775 there